# In SQL, other than strings what are the nonnumeric data types that MIN, MAX, and COUNT operate on?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I'm reading that the aggregate functions  MIN, MAX, and COUNT operate on strings plus other nonnumeric data types. But which ones, and why are they needed?

Thank You

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Different ones have different data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various time types should work with MIN, MAX and COUNT.

In fact, COUNT should work with pretty much any type with the probable exception of large objects (BLOB, CLOB or related types).

Comment: min and max will work with everything but maybe BLOBs and CLOBs as well.